# Restart custom daemon when dependencies were updated

Tags: ubuntu, apt, subversion

I have the following problem/requirements:

On a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system I'm running Subversion installed from an external repository (WANDisco). This repository is well maintained and provides regular updates to subversion (e.g. 1.9.x branch). Whenever subversion is updated so is the required library libsvn.

I'm using a custom upstart script to start svnserve, which works well and does what it should do. Additionally I'm using unattended-upgrades to keep my system up-to-date. I have included the WANDisco repository to provide updates for unattended-upgrades. This works all as intended and I don't want to change this behaviour.

My problem is that whenever an update for subversion is installed my custom daemon isn't restarted resulting in failures when clients want to connect. I then have to manually restart the daemon.

Is there any way to tell apt the dependency between subversion and my svnserve daemon so that it is stopped before a subversion update and started again afterwards (same behaviour as with e.g. mysql updates)?